# First array from query PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have a problem with my code. I want to get the first array from query and show it, after what show the next 2.

For the first Array in query I want to show img for the next 2 only the title

My code:

```
$link = mysql_connect('server', 'user', 'password')
        or die("Can't");
$db = mysql_select_db('database')
      or die ("can't");
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM News LIMIT 3';
$retval = mysql_query($sql,$link);
$filename ="footer.html";
$handle = fopen("footer.html", 'w+');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    //echo "<pre>"; print_r($row); echo "</pre>";
    $content = '<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
        <div class="block_articles">
        <div class="block_header" >
        <div class="headerlink" >
        <a href="'.$sitelink.'" target="_blank"></div></div>';
    $content .= '<img src="'.$sitelink.'news/'.$row['ImageName'].'" alt="'.htmlspecialchars($row['Title']).'" >';   
    $content .= '<a href="="">'.$row['Title'].'</a>';
    $content .= '<div class="date">';
    $content .= $row['Date'];
    $content .= '</div>';
    $content .= '</div>';
    echo $row['Title'].'<br>';
    if ($handle) 
    {
        if (!fwrite($handle, $content))
        die("can't");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're just starting to learn PHP, learn using the MySQLi or PDO extensions with prepared statements and bind variables, rather than learning using the old, deprecated MySQL extension.

Comment: could you tell us what went wrong with your code  ?

Comment: take the `row` in an `array`,you'll get all the rows

Comment: I want to insert in html file only the first array of query...the next 2 I want to echo them

Comment: in the loop each time you'll get only one row only!! in the next loop second row....

Comment: For the first array of the query I want to show <img> for next 2 only the title

Comment: You really should have clearly stated what you want in the question and put a little thought into it, rather than graaaadually telling us what you really want in the comments.

Comment: add a counter to your loop, then if counter==1 show img, else show title

Comment: Very simple...thx..I add a counter variable in loop

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, you want to use a basic loop counter and change the behavior based on the counter:

```
theCurrentRow = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    theCurrentRow++;
    if (theCurrentRow == 1) {
    //show the images
    }
    else {
    // show the title
    }

}
```

Also to reiterate @AmalMurali's comment:  don't use mysql_* functions, they're deprecated: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php